# How to display post title of each particular month in my archive list?

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I am displaying my archive list in the side bar i have displayed the year and month but unable to find any help on google to display the Blogs posts related to each month under them like this

```
2016 
  October
  Blog Topic 1
  Blog Topic 2
  September
  Blog topic 1
  Blog Topic 2
```

My code for displaying year and month is given as under which is working fine but its not showing the blog posts titles of each particular month :

```
 <ul class="archive-list">

    <?php global $wpdb, $month, $sposts;

$years =  $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y')
FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y')
ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC");

if ( $years && count($years) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $years as $y ) { ?>

           <li><?php echo $y; ?></li>
           <li>
           <?php 

            $months =  $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%m')
FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
AND DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y') = $y
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC");

            if ($months) { ?>
                <ul><?php
                foreach($months as $m) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_month_link($y, $m).'">'.$month[zeroise($m, 2)]."</a></li>";
                } ?>
                <!-- START:post title-->
    <?php 


    $sql = "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE
    post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y') = $y
    AND DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%m') = $m
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
foreach( $results as $result )
 { echo $result->post_title; }

    ?>

                <!--END:post title-->

                </ul><?php
            } ?>
        <?php
    }?>
    </ul>
```

Right Now it is showing output like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you `print_r($results);` and post the output?

Comment: i have attached the output image above

Comment: No, I mean try `print_r($results);` before the loop and show us the output.

Comment: What do you mean nothing? Then if there's nothing, you are not fetching any data from the database.

Comment: ok thanks for ur feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124775/discussion-between-sadia-rashid-and-rax-weber).